# Find Jordan basis for $\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, \phi((x_1,x_2,x_3))=(4x_1-x_2,4x_1,8x_1-4x_2+2x_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

I am looking for a Jordan basis for $\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, \phi((x_1,x_2,x_3))=(4x_1-x_2,4x_1,8x_1-4x_2+2x_3)$.

The matrix of the transformation in the standard basis is

$$A=M(\phi)_{\mathcal{st}}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & -1 & 0 \\
        4 & 0 & 0 \\
        8 & -4 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial is $p_\phi(\lambda)=(2-\lambda)^3$, $r((A-2I)^0)-r((A-2I)^1)=3-1=2$ so the Jordan matrix must have two blocks of size $\ge 1$. I choose one of the possible Jordan forms
$$M(\phi)_{\mathcal{A}}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
From this, I know that for vectors from $\mathcal{A}$ we must have $$\phi(\alpha_1)=2\alpha_1$$
$$\phi(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1+2\alpha_2$$
$$\phi(\alpha_3)=2\alpha_3$$
This means that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$ are the eigenvectors, for instance
$\alpha_1=(1,2,0),\alpha_3=(0,0,1)$.
Now
$$\phi(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1+2\alpha_2$$
$$\phi(\alpha_2)-2\alpha_2=\alpha_1$$
$$\phi(\alpha_2)-2\text{id}(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1$$
$$(\phi-2\text{id})(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1$$
so
$$(A-2I)\alpha_2=\alpha_1$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -1 & 0 \\
        4 & -2 & 0 \\
        8 & -4 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
This system doesn't have a solution and we are one vector short. What am I missing?

Comment: Why must $(A-2I)\alpha_2$ equal $\alpha_1$? Why not $\alpha_3$? Or some linear combination of them, like $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @BobJones We are looking for $\mathcal{A}$. $M(\phi)_{\mathcal{A}}$ gives us the condition $\phi(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1+2\alpha_2$ (from the definition of $M(\phi)_{\mathcal{B}}=M(\phi)_{\mathcal{B}}^{{\mathcal{B}}}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis). Then we use this to get to $(\phi-2\text{id})(\alpha_2)=\alpha_1$ which, in matrix form, can be written as the equation you're asking about. I was able to work through several examples using this approach and get to a system I was able to solve. This time, I feel I'm missing something basic.

Comment: Yes, the thing you're missing is that the eigenvectors space does not have to be generated by those two vectors; you cannot just pick two vectors in the space and declare them to be $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$. Because $\alpha_1$ must be in the image of $A-2I$, you have to take that into account and pick an $\alpha_1$ that works for that. Like my vector I gave. Then you may choose $\alpha_2$ in the preimage, and $\alpha_3$ to complete the eigenspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we know at this stage is that $\{ (1,2,0), (0,0,1) \}$ is a basis for ${\rm Ker}(A-2I)$.

We cannot just pick any random vector in ${\rm Ker}(A - 2I)$ to be our $\alpha_1$; we need to find one that works.

First, let us add a vector to $\{ (1,2,0), (0,0,1) \}$ to form a complete basis for $\mathbb R^3$. Call this extra basis vector $\alpha_2$. It doesn't matter which vector we choose for $\alpha_2$, as long as it is linearly independent of $(1,2,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. I'm going to choose
$$\alpha_2 = (1,0,0).$$

This means that $\alpha_1$ must be
$$ \alpha_1 = (A - 2I) \alpha_2 = (2,4,8). $$
[Note that, once $\alpha_2$ has been chosen, we do *not* get to choose $\alpha_1$!]

Finally, we can pick $\alpha_3$ to be any vector in the linear span of $\{ (1,2,0),(0,0,1)\}$ that is not a multiple of $\alpha_1$. Again, it doesn't matter which one we choose, so I'm going to go for
$$ \alpha_3 = (0,0,1).$$

Thus we have constructed a basis
$$\alpha_1 = (2,4,8), \ \ \  \alpha_2 = (1,0,0), \ \ \ \alpha_3 = (0,0,1)$$
that obeys the desired properties,
$$ A \alpha_1 = 2 \alpha_1, \ \ \ A \alpha_2 = \alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2, \ \ \ A \alpha_3 = 2 \alpha_3.$$

By the way, it is better to "start at the top and work down" than to "start at the bottom and work up". Said another way, it is better to *start* with a basis vector $\alpha_2$ in ${\rm Ker}(A - 2I)^2 = \mathbb R^3$ that is not in ${\rm Ker}(A-2I)$, and *then* complete the basis of $\mathbb R^3$ by choosing a vector $\alpha_3$ in ${\rm Ker}(A- 2I)$ complementary to both $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_1 = (A - 2I)\alpha_2$. You can easily generalise this approach and turn it into an algorithm that works in all cases.